# Is this the correct way to express no value in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a accordion which has been set up to open to a specific panel by appending this string to the URL`?panel=0`

```
farfegnugen = jQuery.noConflict();

        farfegnugen(document).ready(function($) {
            var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));
           farfegnugen("#st-accordion").accordion({
                open: defaultPanel
            });

            function getParam(name) {
                var query = location.search.substring(1);
                if (query.length) {
                    var parts = query.split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
                        if (parts[i].substring(0, pos) == name) {
                            return parts[i].substring(pos + 1);
                        }
                    }
                } else if(query.length === undefined){
                    window.location.href = "#topOfPage";
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

However, I have noticed it scrolls slightly to the body of the accordion on load despite not having selected a specific panel. To fix this behavior I figured adding this `else if` block would check to see if the parameter was empty, if so we would force the window to scroll where that `anchor` is situated.

```
<a id="topOfPage" href='#'></a>
```

So wouldn't `else if(query.length === undefined)` work because you're saying nothing, is there? 
P.S. I tried `null` too, and that didn't work!

Comment: length is a number, so compare to zero

Answer (score 0):

Try running `location.search.substring(1).length` in your console and you will see what the issue is. It is equal to `0` which is not `undefined`. In your case, you don't need an `else if`, you can simply use an `else`

Comment: Thanks! SO in my conditional I changed  it to `if (query.length !== 0)` this would say if not zero do the normal functionality but if it is zero (e.g. else) `window.location.href = "#topOfPage";` Strangely, that didn't work.

Comment: You can leave your original conditional `if(query.length)`

Comment: I tried that, followed by `else{window.location.href = "#topOfPage";}` and no dice. I wonder if it's the anchor? Is `<a id="topOfPage" href='#'></a>
` correct?